# basic json decode question

Tags: php, json

good evening. ingore all other elements, I want get first image in each foreach. how to?

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($data['data'][0] as $image) { 
        echo '<img src="'.$image['images'][0]['source'][0].'" />';
    }
```

json tree is too large, over the letters paste limit.

```
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 68494
```

so here is the url u can get the json tree https://graph.facebook.com/5550296508/photos

and u can paste in http://jsonlint.com/  look the struction well. Thanx.

Comment: The JSON data is not your problem here. The structure you've shown is only 10K in size. So the error message (`limited 30000 characters`) originates elsewhere. Explain what you are attempting to do with the html output.

Comment: @mario,excuse me, the error because the post, not json problem. my problem is get all the first image in `data[0]` foreach, all the `_n.jpg` end images. and ingore all the other elements. only the images. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `json_decode` every `{}` (object) will become an `object(stdClass)` and every `[]` (array) will become an `array`. So:

```
$data->data[0]->images[0]->source
```

is what you need, to reach the first image source.

**Edit:** since the second parameter of `json_decode` is `true`, it will become an associative array, and it will be like:

```
$data['data'][0]['images'][0]['source']
```

To get all the images:

```
$images = array();
foreach ($data['data'] as $d)
{
    foreach ($d['images'] as $i)
    {
        $images[] = $i['source'];
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get all the images? there are many `images[0]->source` in the foreach `data[0]`, and some are empty, some have image?

Comment: so if write into a foreach, it will wrong to get back data. `foreach ($data['data'][0] as $image){echo '<img src="'.$data['images'][0]['source'].'" />';}` why?

Comment: What you commented here is not correct. I added my version to the answer, but here is your last snippet, corrected: `foreach ($data['data'] as $d) { echo '<img src="'.$d['images'][0]['source'].'" />'; }`